# Find the limits for this function

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limits

$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x^2 sin^2 (x)} {x^2 - sin^2 (x)}$

Comment: Maclaurin series.

Comment: Fix the numerator as $x^{4}\cdot\dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}$ and then it can be replaced by $x^{4}$. Factor denominator and then the expression is split as a product of $x/(x + \sin x)$ and $x^{3}/(x - \sin x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2 \sin^2 x}{x^2-\sin^2 x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2}{x^2\csc^2 x-1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2}{(x\csc x-1)(x\csc x +1)} = \dfrac 1 2\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{x^2}{x\csc x-1}$

Then apply l'Hospital's Rule ($\times 2$).

Comment: I couldn't get the final answer after applying l'hopital rule.
So can you tell me what will be the final answer?

Answer (score 0):

We have: $L = \dfrac{x\sin x}{x-\sin x}\cdot \dfrac{x\sin x}{x+\sin x}$, and apply L'hospitale rule for each factor of the product. The first one you do twice, and the second you only need once.

Comment: The way you have split, the first factor goes to $\pm\infty$ and second factor goes to $0$. It is simply wrong.

Comment: I have read it again and i still stand by my previous comment.

Comment: Can you put the final answer?